# Turf.js buffer distance not accurate

Tags: openlayers, buffer, turf

I'm facing a strange behavior using buffers in Turf.js.

When trying to do a 50m buffer around a point, the result is actually closer to 35m.

On the screenshot below, the smaller circle is a turf.buffer() and the bigger one is a turf.circle() using the same radius/distance. This second one is correct.

[image]

Here's my code :

```
var map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [
     new ol.layer.Tile({
       source: new ol.source.OSM()
     })
   ],
   view: new ol.View({
     center: ol.proj.transform([5, 45], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
     zoom: 17
   })
});

var distance = 50

var center = turf.point([5, 45])

var bufferedWgs84 = turf.buffer(center, distance/1000, {units: 'kilometers'});

var circleWgs84 = turf.circle(center, distance/1000, {units: 'kilometers'});

var buffer = turf.toMercator(bufferedWgs84)

var circle = turf.toMercator(circleWgs84)

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ 
                source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#737373',
                width: 2
                })
            })
            });
map.addLayer(layer);
layer.getSource().addFeature(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeature(buffer))
layer.getSource().addFeature(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeature(circle))
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fhkgzd2o/1/

Comment: The distances in EPSG:3857 coordinate system are inaccurate and one meter on the ground gets longer towards the poles. https://www.giserdqy.com/wp-content/guids/ol-v5.1.3/examples/tissot.html. Perhaps turf takes this into account with one method but not with the other.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, a loss in precision when using the turf.toMercator().  But actually, even when staying in 4326 I have the same result (see here exemple with Leaflet :  https://jsfiddle.net/u7jbgmLo/1/ )

Comment: I tried to use "meters" as unit, even if it's not a possible unit according to the documentation (that's why I used kilometers). It seems to work but same problem  : https://jsfiddle.net/kfgbjyc0/1/

Comment: Looks like a known problem of the latest version, they suggest to roll back to v4.7.3 and it should be fixed in v7  (current version I'm using is 5.1.6 : https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1484

Comment: Turf Circle vs Turf Buffer vs Leaflet Circle, This example was to compare drawing a circle from the Leaflet Draw tool to a circle in Turf buffer. I noticed a difference even though I passed them the same center point and radius. To confirm the result I used Turf Circle and it corresponded with the Leaflet drawing. The red circle is Turf buffer, black is Turf circle, and white dashed is leaflet circle. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/drawCircle/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Simple experiment show it's really question of projection. If you take coordinate [0, 0] as center of the circle and buffer, they match. If you calculate factor for diameter difference betwee buffer and circle at 45° of latitude, you get approximately 1.41, whch is exactly the value of Mercator projection length factor `1/Math.cos(latitude*Math.PI/180)`.

This tells that `turf.circle` has real diameter and `turf.buffer` method somehow behaves as having diameter at latitude 0° in projected CRS. To get the same result as with `turf.circle` method, diameter has to be multiplied with Mercator projection length factor.

**EDIT (July 2022)**:
This problem  was present with turf.js version 5.1.6. It is corrected now with version 6.5.0.